# How to fix The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am going to assign some parameter values in the cursor in SQL Server, like this:

```
DECLARE insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        @CompanyID = CompanyID,
        @APID_Master_Id = APOD_Master_Id,
        @APID_Project_Id = APOD_Project_Id,
        @APID_Item_Num = APOD_Item_Num,
        @APID_Project_Code = APOD_Project_Code,
        @APID_Item_Id = APOD_Item_Id,
        @apid_cost_centre_id = apod_cost_centre_id
    FROM 
        Account_APOrderDetail aod
    WHERE
        aod.APOD_Master_Id IN (SELECT ref_code
                               FROM Account_APOrderMaster
                               WHERE apo_order_id = 00122975);
```

But when the run query, I get this error message

> Msg 154, Level 15, State 3, Line 110
>   Variable assignment is not allowed in a cursor declaration.

How can fix this?

**edit question**

```
DECLARE @Create_UserId uniqueidentifier,
        @Create_Date datetime,
        @Modification_UserId uniqueidentifier,
        @Modification_Date datetime,

SET @Create_UserId = '535EFDB6-CA05-4DB3-A379-E3D65CF9C08F';
SET @Create_Date = '2017-05-16 08:51:10.080';
SET @Modification_UserId = '535EFDB6-CA05-4DB3-A379-E3D65CF9C08F';
SET @Modification_Date = '2017-06-29 17:06:20.103';

DECLARE insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor CURSOR FOR
select 
CompanyID,APOD_Master_Id,APOD_Project_Id,APOD_Item_Num,APOD_Project_Code, APOD_Item_Id,apod_cost_centre_id
from Account_APOrderDetail aod
where aod.APOD_Master_Id in (
select ref_code
from Account_APOrderMaster
where apo_order_id = 00122975

);
OPEN insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor INTO

.....
```

Comment: *How can fix this?* - **do not** assign values to SQL variables in your `SELECT` that is in your cusor definition - just have a "regular" `SELECT` that returns column values from a table. **Or even better:** change your SQL to entirely avoid using a cursor in the first place - in 99% of the cases, you can do without and get much better performance, too!

Comment: did as you.now got this error ''Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 126 Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.''

Comment: Just count the **number of columns** that your `SELECT` in the cursor returns, and check to see if you have **the same number** of SQL variables to store the values into. If you get this error, you obviously have a mismatch somewhere.....

Comment: actually I did several times but I could not find any one mismatch

Comment: @marc_s OK i have some variables outside of the select statement. in your point may I should paste here only variable that include in the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the assignment in the `Fetch Into` part of the cursor

```
DECLARE insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        CompanyID, APOD_Master_Id, APOD_Project_Id, 
        APOD_Item_Num, APOD_Project_Code, APOD_Item_Id, apod_cost_centre_id
    FROM
        Account_APOrderDetail aod
    WHERE 
        aod.APOD_Master_Id IN (SELECT ref_code
                               FROM Account_APOrderMaster
                               WHERE apo_order_id = 00122975);
OPEN insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM insertapiinvoicedetail_cursor 
     INTO @CompanyID, @APID_Master_Id, @APID_Project_Id, @APID_Item_Num, 
          @APID_Project_Code, @APID_Item_Id, @apid_cost_centre_id

...
```

Comment: did as you.now got this error ''Msg 16924, Level 16, State 1, Line 126
Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.''

Comment: @kathirina make sure the order and number of columns in the select must match with that of the variables in the into part. Also, i forgot to open the cursor I've edited that now

Comment: OK i have some variables outside of the select statement. in your point may I should paste here only variable that include in the select statement?

Comment: The Fetch Into statement targets the output of the select Statement into the defined variables. So yes, you should only paste the variables that are a target for the select statement

Comment: Why do you need to select other variable in thr declaration part of the cursor? I'd suggest you edit your question and post your entire code with your  requirement. As @marc_s mentioned you may even not need a cursor.

Comment: I edit my question here can you give me some solutions?

Comment: my new question here

Comment: @kathirina your updated question's code seems fine except that you have an extra comma `,` after the variable declaration. Just note that the variables that you are setting outside of the cursor will be set only once whereas those in the fetch into target will be updated for every row that the select statement of the cursor outputs. Look here for more information on  how and when to use cursors https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: cursor is very new for me. can you give me some example code here?